# Checking for a lowercase character or space in a string. Boolean not working

Tags: c++

This is supposed to check if an entered string is a valid license number. A valid number cannot have any lower case letters or spaces. If I enter "cat", it should see that the character "c" is lower so it should set bool isValid to false, break from the loop and then print "cat is not a valid license number." However it doesn't and it just makes the bool isValid to whatever I set it to in the beginning which was true. So if I initialized it to false and input "CAT" isValid would still be false.

```
int main()
{
    // Input
    cout << "Enter a valid license number: ";
    string license_number;
    getline(cin, license_number);
    cout << endl;

    // Initialize boolean
    bool isValid = true;

    // Loop to check for space or lowercase
    for (int i = 0; i < license_number.size(); i++)
    {
        if (isspace(license_number[i]) || islower(license_number[i]))
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            break;
        }

        else
            bool isValid = true;
    }

    // Output
    if (isValid == true)
        cout << license_number << " is a valid license number." << endl;

    else
        cout << license_number << " is not a valid license number." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
bool isValid = false;
    break;
```

You're not changing your `isValid` variable. Instead, you're making a new `isValid` that shadows the original `isValid`, and that new variable is discarded immediately as it goes out of scope right afterwards. As a result, your original `isValid` is unaffected. Remove the `bool` in this line and it'll work.

---

Other than that you can also remove this part

```
else
    bool isValid = true;
```

Because `isValid` is `true` anyway when this part of the code is reached. Also instead of `if (isValid == true)` you can simply write `if (isValid)`. You could even simplify the code like this:

```
// Loop to check for space or lowercase
for (int i = 0; i < license_number.size(); i++)
{
    if (isspace(license_number[i]) || islower(license_number[i]) )
    {
        cout << license_number << " is not a valid license number." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

cout << license_number << " is a valid license number." << endl;

return 0;
```

Also, if you have the time, have a look at [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `bool` type from the for loop (in `if` and `else` condition) - it defines a new local variable `isValid` which shadows the `isValid` definition which is outside the loop (under comment `// Initialize boolean`) & this local definition cease to exist as soon as the command flow go out of the block where it has been defined.

And outside that block the definition `isValid = true` again comes into play (which remained untouched from the processing logic).